# Determine if a transformation is a linear transformation or not

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

$T(x_{1},x_{2}) = |2x_{1} + x_{2}|$.

Does this transformation a linear transformation?

Attempt:

$1)$ Let $(x_{1},y_{1}) , (x_{2},y_{2})$ two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, Then:

$T(x_{1},y_{1}) + T(x_{2},y_{2}) = |2x_{1} + y_{1}| + |2x_{2} + y{2}|
 = |2x_{1} + 2x_{2} + y_{1} + y_{2}|$

$ = T(x_{1}+x_{2} , y_{1}+y_{2})$.

$2)$ Let $a $ be a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$, and $(x_{1},y_{1})$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, Then:

$aT(x_{1},y_{1})=a|2x_{1}+y_{1}| $

$T(ax_{1},ay_{1}) = |a2x_{1}+ay_{1}| $

Is it true to say that $T$ is a non linear transformation because:

$aT(x_{1},y_{1})$ is not the same of $T(ax_{1},ay_{1})$ ?

Comment: Pick specific numbers and see. How about $T(1,1), T(-1,-1)$? Note that there is exactly one linear functional that takes non negative values.

Comment: The equalities in your "attempt" are not all true

Answer (score 1):

Any linear map from $R^2 \rightarrow R$ is of the form $T(x,y)=ax+by$ Thus $T$ is differentiable but your function is clearly not at (0,0)

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is not a linear transformation.

$T(-2,2)+T(1,1)=|-4+2|+|2+1|=5$

$T((-2,2)+(1,1))=T(-1,3)=1 \neq 5$